# SCP not working from AWS ec2 instance when trying -i

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2, scp

I am trying to scp a file to my computer with the command:

```
sudo scp -i Documents/Professional/DiscMix/TestFile.pem ec2-user@-----.-----.compute-1.amazonaws.com: /csr.pem
```

But I keep getting the error: `scp: .: not a regular file`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't put the location to download in the command at the very end. My final command is:
 `sudo scp -i DiscMixEc2.pem ec2-user@------.------.compute-1.amazonaws.com:~/csr.pem Downloads`

Answer (score 1):

I see that name of the file to copy is missing.
Update your command as shown below to make it work.

```
sudo scp filetocopy.csv -i Documents/Professional/DiscMix/TestFile.pem ec2-user@ec2-34-xxx-xx-xxx.compute-3.amazonaws.com:/csr.pem
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 sudo scp -i DiscMixEc2.pem ec2-user@------.------.compute-1.amazonaws.com:/tmp
```

try first copying it to temporary folder and from there manually copy to u r destination folder.